Reference for lower bound for realizable PAC learning sample complexity?
Suppose $\mathcal{F} \subset \{0, 1\}^\mathcal{X}$ be a class of functions and denote by $D_m(f) := \{(X_i, f(X_i))\}_{i=1}^m$ a dataset. Here, $X_i$ are iid samples from distribution $P$ on $\mathcal{X}$.
We can define the optimal sample complexity, assuming realizability $f \in \mathcal{F}$ as follows:
$$
m_{P, \mathcal{F}}^{\rm opt}(\epsilon, \delta) = \min\{m \geq 1 : \exists \hat f~\text{s.t.}~\text{Pr}_{D_m(f)}[\text{err}_P(\hat f, f) > \epsilon] \leq \delta~\text{for all}~f\in \mathcal{F}\}.
$$
Above, $\text{err}_P(g, f) = P(g(X) \neq f(X))$.
Thus, $m^{\rm opt}_{P, \mathcal{F}}(\epsilon, \delta)$ is the smallest number of samples for which there exists an algorithm under which I can $(\epsilon,\delta)$-PAC-learn $f$ with access to samples $D_m(f)$.
It is possible to show that ERM can $(\epsilon, \delta)$-PAC learn with $m > \frac{\log(|\mathcal{F}|/\delta)}{\epsilon}$ many samples.
Hence, $m^{\rm opt}_{P, \mathcal{F}}(\epsilon, \delta) \leq O(\tfrac{\log(|\mathcal{F}|/\delta)}{\epsilon})$.
Question:
Is there a reference showing this is sharp? In other words what is a reference that demonstrates that for every integer $M \geq 2$, there exists an problem instance $(P, \mathcal{F})$ with $|\mathcal{F}| = M$ for which $m^{\rm opt}_{P, \mathcal{F}}(\epsilon, \delta) \geq \Omega(\tfrac{\log(|\mathcal{F}|/\delta)}{\epsilon})$?

VC-dimension is a lower bound, so just take any class with VCdim equal to log size. One such class is the class of all functions on a finite set $\mathcal{X}$.

Sure, even in that case, I am asking what reference actually proves this result?

If there are any pedagogical sources too, that would be great. Most places I looked either didn't have the result, or if they did, they only consider $\delta = O(1)$.

have u checked "understanding machine learning" and "foundations of machine learning"?

See Chapter 5 of Neural Network Learning: Theoretical Foundations by Anthony and Bartlett.
